# Already included the file name.....?

Tags: angularjs, config.json

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

src/app/app.module.ts:7:35 - error TS1149: File name 'E:/Angular Project/hamza-todo-list/src/app/MyComponents/todo-item/todo-item.component.ts' differs from already included file name 'E:/Angular Project/hamza-todo-list/src/app/MYComponents/todo-item/todo-item.component.ts' only in casing.
The file is in the program because:
Imported via '../todo-item/todo-item.component' from file 'E:/Angular Project/hamza-todo-list/src/app/MYComponents/todos/todos.component.ngtypecheck.ts'
Imported via './todo-item.component' from file 'E:/Angular Project/hamza-todo-list/src/app/MYComponents/todo-item/todo-item.component.ngtypecheck.ts'
Imported via './MyComponents/todo-item/todo-item.component' from file 'E:/Angular Project/hamza-todo-list/src/app/app.module.ts'

7 import { TodoItemComponent } from './MyComponents/todo-item/todo-item.component';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/MYComponents/todos/todos.component.ngtypecheck.ts:4:21
4 import * as i3 from '../todo-item/todo-item.component';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
File is included via import here.
src/app/MYComponents/todo-item/todo-item.component.ngtypecheck.ts:1:21
1 import * as i0 from './todo-item.component';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
File is included via import here.

Guys i'm new programing...don't know what this error is about???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two imports differ in case...

```
MyComponents/todo-item/todo-item.component.ts
```

and

```
MYComponents/todo-item/todo-item.component.ts
 ^-----
```

(note the uppercase 'Y')